# Create view in phpMyAdmin from three tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a view in MySQL, using phpMyAdimn, which will display data from three tables, in the format below. It needs to be sorted by last name, first name. I've never pulled data from more than one table before and this is difficult for me to grasp. I need to get this to work as soon as possible so I can create reports in Google Data Studio for our client.

Thanks...

### View needs to present data in this order, and is named UserCourseProgress.

Last Name, First Name, Email, Group (Atlanta, Charleston, Greenvile, Nashville), Course Progress, Completion Date

### Tables and columns in database.

```
TABLES                      COLUMNS
wp_users                    user_email
wp_usermeta                 first_name, last_name, wp_2_capabilities
wp_2_wpcw_user_progress     unit_completed_status, unit_completed_date
```

### Code I've tried.

```
CREATE VIEW UserCourseProgress AS
SELECT 
    wp_users.user_email, wp_usermeta.first_name, wp_usermeta.last_name, wp_usermeta.wp_2_capabilities, wp_2_wpcw_user_progress.unit_completed_status, wp_2_wpcw_user_progress.unit_completed_date
FROM 
    wp_users,
    wp_usermeta,
    wp_2_wpcw_user_progress
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON (wp_users.user_email=wp_usermeta.first_name) AND (wp_users.user_email=wp_usermeta.last_name) AND (wp_users.user_email=wp_usermeta.wp_2_capabilities)
INNER JOIN wp_2_wpcw_user_progress (wp_users.user_email=wp_2_wpcw_user_progress.unit_completed_status) AND (wp_users.user_email=wp_2_wpcw_user_progress.unit_completed_date)
```

Comment: Why a VIEW as such?

Comment: As I said in the first post, Google Data Studio needs an mySQL view to use data from multiple tables.

Comment: Thinking now that I need to use IDs to match the fields.

Comment: Well, I don't understand why you have a comma join followed by an explicit join on the same tables!?!

Comment: And I hav eto admit to being totally mystified by this bit: `INNER JOIN wp_2_wpcw_user_progress (wp_users.user_email=wp_2_wpcw_user_progress.unit_completed_status) `

Comment: Why would a completed date correspond to an email? I fear you're trying to run before you can walk!

Comment: Strawberry, I don't understand the comma join either, as I am a novice with queries that are for multiple tables. The inner join you mentions was a mistake in my editing. I overlooked it. For the record, I finally got it to work and post the solution below, in the event it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question here. Let me state that I'm a novice with MySQL queries, but some of you may have guessed that.

I studied many examples before I was able to get my query to work, and it took several hours, over several days. The code for my solution is as follows and it works. I still haven't figured out how to concatenate the data in wp_2_capabilities to only show the role, and not the serialized data, but that is for another day.

Thanks for the input, to the ones who did.

### MY SOLUTION

```
CREATE VIEW CourseProgress AS
SELECT
    wp_users.ID,
    wp_users.user_email,
    firstmeta.meta_value AS first_name,
    lastmeta.meta_value AS last_name,
    rolemeta.meta_value AS wp_2_capabilities,
    unitprogress.unit_completed_status
FROM
    wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS firstmeta
ON
    wp_users.ID = firstmeta.user_id AND firstmeta.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS lastmeta
ON
    wp_users.ID = lastmeta.user_id AND lastmeta.meta_key = 'last_name'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS rolemeta
ON
    wp_users.ID = rolemeta.user_id AND rolemeta.meta_key = 'wp_2_capabilities'
LEFT JOIN wp_2_wpcw_user_progress AS unitprogress
ON
    wp_users.ID = unitprogress.user_id AND unitprogress.unit_completed_status = 'complete'
WHERE
    rolemeta.meta_value REGEXP 'gs_atlanta|gs_charleston|gs_greenvilee|gs_nashville'
ORDER BY
    wp_users.ID;
```